# CRUD using spring and mybatis

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mybatis

**HI hava a problem while creating a CRUD operation in browser**

```
`HTTP Status 500 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message 

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'standard' of bean class [com.raistudies.domain.User]: Bean property 'standard' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:548)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:456)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

**here I have all part of the spring mvc + mybatis operations file**
//controller

```
package com.raistudies.controllers;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.raistudies.domain.User;
import com.raistudies.persistence.UserService;
import com.raistudies.validator.RegistrationValidator;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/registration")
public class RegistrationController {

private RegistrationValidator validator = null;
private UserService userService = null;

@Autowired
public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}

public RegistrationValidator getValidator() {
    return validator;
}

@Autowired
public void setValidator(RegistrationValidator validator) {
    this.validator = validator;
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm(ModelMap model){
    List<User> users = userService.getAllUser();
    model.addAttribute("users", users);
    User user = new User();
    user.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "registration";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView add(@ModelAttribute(value="user") User user,BindingResult result){
    validator.validate(user, result);
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("registration");
    if(!result.hasErrors()){
        userService.saveUser(user);
        user = new User();
        user.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        mv.addObject("user", user);
    }
    mv.addObject("users", userService.getAllUser());
    return mv;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/update", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView update(@ModelAttribute(value="user") User user,BindingResult result){
    validator.validate(user, result);
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("registration");
    if(!result.hasErrors()){
        userService.updateUser(user);
        user = new User();
        user.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        mv.addObject("user", user);
    }
    mv.addObject("users", userService.getAllUser());
    return mv;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/delete", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView delete(@ModelAttribute(value="user") User user,BindingResult result){
    validator.validate(user, result);
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("registration");
    if(!result.hasErrors()){
        userService.deleteUser(user.getId());
        user = new User();
        user.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        mv.addObject("user", user);
    }
    mv.addObject("users", userService.getAllUser());
    return mv;
}
 }
```

**persistance is**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" 
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="com.raistudies.persistence.UserService">

<resultMap id="result" type="user">
    <result property="id" column="id"/>
    <result property="name" column="name"/>
    <result property="studentClass" column="class"/>
    <result property="roll" column="roll"/>
   <!--  <result property="sex" column="sex"/>-->
</resultMap>

<select id="getAllUser" resultMap="result">  
    SELECT id,name,class,roll
    FROM user; 
</select>

<insert id="saveUser" parameterType="user">
    INSERT INTO user (id,name,standard,age,sex) 
    VALUE (#{id},#{name},#{standard},#{age})
</insert>

<update id="updateUser" parameterType="user"> 
    UPDATE user
    SET
        name = #{name},  
        standard = #{standard},  
        age = #{age},  
        sex = #{sex} 
    where id = #{id} 
</update>

  <delete id="deleteUser" parameterType="int">
    DELETE FROM user
    WHERE id = #{id}
  </delete>
  </mapper>
```

I have to do create delete update add operation but it is going to be error just like above while running my project......please help me

Comment: Oups ! AFAIK, the error says you have a problem in a jsp file where you try to access probably `user.standard` ... still far from a problem in myBatis persistance

Comment: oh! is it?let me see.@SergeBallesta

Comment: `Invalid property 'standard' of bean class [com.raistudies.domain.User]: Bean property 'standard' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?`    but what does it mean,please could you tell me?@SergeBallesta

Comment: @SergeBallesta Actually what I am doing is, I am trying to change the project which can be download at the [link..http://www.raistudies.com/spring-mvc-tutorial/ ] ....instead of the domain it has, I have to this  student_name  varchar
2) student_roll  number 
3) student_class number
4) student_id  number  primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after changing the jsp code as per the variable that the java bean class(class containing geter or setter method) has.Then it will solve the problem.

***especially what I mean is you have to change the path in jsp `<tr><td>Class : </td><td><form:input path="standard" /></td></tr>`*as per the bean variable**

**previous jsp file (at error time)**

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ page session="true" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Hello World with Spring 3 MVC</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
    <script type="text/javascript" src='<c:url value="/resources/common.js"/>'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='<c:url value="/resources/registration.js"/>'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var projectUrl = '<c:url value="/"/>';
        if(projectUrl.indexOf(";", 0) != -1){
            projectUrl = projectUrl.substring(0, projectUrl.indexOf(";", 0));
        }
    </script>       
</head>
<body>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Registration Form</legend>
    <center>
    <form:form commandName="user" action="/SpringMVCMyBatisCRUDExample/app/registration/add" name="userForm">

    <form:hidden path="id"/>
    <table>
        <tr><td colspan="2" align="left"><form:errors path="*" cssStyle="color : red;"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Name : </td><td><form:input path="name" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Class : </td><td><form:input path="standard" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>RollNo: </td><td><form:input path="roll" /></td></tr>

        <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Save Changes"/>
        &nbsp;<input type="reset" name="newUser" value="New User" onclick="setAddForm();" disabled="disabled"/>
        &nbsp;<input type="submit" name="deleteUser" value="Delete User" onclick="setDeleteForm();" disabled="disabled"/></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form:form>
    </center>
    </fieldset>
    <c:if test="${!empty users}">

        <br />
        <center>
            <table width="90%">
                <tr style="background-color: gray;">
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Class</th>
                    <th>RollNo</th>

                </tr>
                <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
                    <tr style="background-color: silver;" id="${user.id}" onclick="setUpdateForm('${user.id}');">
                        <td><c:out value="${user.name}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${user.studentClass}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${user.roll}"/></td>

                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </table>
            </center>
        <br />

    </c:if>
</body>
```

**my java bean class**

```
package com.raistudies.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;


public class User implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 3647233284813657927L;

private String id;
private String name = null;
private String studentClass = null;
private String roll;    

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getStudentClass() {
    return studentClass;
}

public void setStudentClass(String studentClass) {
    this.studentClass = studentClass;
}

public String getRoll() {
    return roll;
}

public void setRoll(String roll) {
    this.roll = roll;
}



@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User [name=" + name + ", class="+ studentClass+ ", roll=" + roll + "]";
}
}
```

previously I had ***standard*** variable in java bean class(model class) but I have to change it to ***studentClass*** so not to be error we must change the jsp path that is

`<tr><td>Class : </td><td><form:input path="standard" /></td></tr>`.......

to

```
<tr><td>Class : </td><td><form:input path="studentClass" /></td></tr>
```